# Simple Regex Question

Tags: c#, regex

I am new to regex (15 minutes of experience) so I can't figure this one out.  I just want something that will match an alphanumeric string with no spaces in it.  For example:

"ThisIsMyName" should match, but
"This Is My Name" should not match.

Comment: I highly recommend using the Regex Tester VS10 extension, if you're using that IDE.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$` will match any letters and any numbers with no spaces (or any punctuation) in the string. It will also require at least one alphanumeric character. This uses a [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) for the matching. Breakdown:

```
^       #Match the beginning of the string
[       #Start of a character class
  a-z   #The range of lowercase letters
  A-Z   #The range of uppercase letters
  0-9   #The digits 0-9
]       #End of the character class
+       #Repeat the previous one or more times
$       #End of string
```

Further, if you want to "capture" the match so that it can be referenced later, you can surround the regex in parens (a [capture group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html)), like so:

```
^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$
```

Even further: since you tagged this with C#, MSDN has a little howto for using regular expressions in .NET. It can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228595%28VS.80%29.aspx). You can also note the fact that if you run the regex with the `RegexOptions.IgnoreCase` flag then you can simplify it to:

`^([a-z0-9])+$`

Comment: Aha, this works perfectly.  I was missing the '$' before.  Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this regex to see if it works: `(\w+)`

Comment: Also be aware that this matches the underscore character.

Answer (score 0):

this will match any sequence of non-space characters:

```
\S+
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this link for a good basic Regex information source: http://regexlib.com/CheatSheet.aspx

They also have a handy testing tool that I use quite a bit: http://regexlib.com/RETester.aspx

That said, @eldarerathis' or @Nicolas Bottarini's answers should work for you.

Answer (score 0):

I have just written a blog entry about regex, maybe it's something you may find useful:)
http://blogs.appframe.com/erikv/2010-09-23-Regular-Expression